# How to toggle cellular data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

**I know this is only possible with private API, this is for a jailbreak tweak NOT the AppStore**

I am trying to toggle the cellular data option of the iPhone. I have found APIs for Bluetooth, Airplane mode, wifi and GPS, but not for 3G or cellular data.

Where can the API for 3G and cellular be found?

Comment: Jonathan, this is an indirect solution, and requires **SBSettings** to be installed, but if you look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363662/using-sbsettings-toggles-to-turn-things-on-or-off), it shows how you can use the SBSettings **Data** toggle, which obviously has already found the correct API, to do the work.  BTW, I have no idea why this question wasn't deemed acceptable, and have voted to reopen (although I wouldn't hold your breath).

Comment: I would recommend to look in SystemConfiguration framework. There are a lot of API there for manipulating networks. I bet some of them could be used to toggle cellular data.